# Using monaco-editor with typescript without webpack in an electron project

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, electron, monaco-editor

I'm trying to use [monaco-editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html) in an electron typescript project. I installed it via
`npm install -D monaco-editor`.
I import it with `import { editor } from "monaco-editor";` My IDE (WebStorm) doesn't complain about an unfound module, however after running the app I get the following error:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'monaco-editor'` from `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801` in the console.

I have already tried

- Downloading the package manualy
- Reinstalling the module
- Cloning the code from the official repository

I was able to run [official samples](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-samples), those however use pure javascript. I also do not use WebPack. I suppose that should not make a difference, however it is used in all getting started and installation guides.

What is the source of that error and how can I fix it?

P.S. You can find the full code on [github](https://github.com/mac501pl/8BitSimulator) if you need more context

Comment: Does npm -D, means this is a development tool not a package that you want at run time?
I am trying just now with npm -S

Comment: Yes, I should't use the -D flag, that is my bad

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work.
So for those who try:

**tsconfig.json**
Try to make the typescript compiler ignore the errors in the monaco library.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
```

**rollup.config.js**
Make the bundler accept importing css files, also adding the line inlineDynamicImports: true fix the compile. I am not sure what the impact is yet.

```
import rollupPluginCssOnly from 'rollup-plugin-css-only'

export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        inlineDynamicImports: true
    },
    plugins: [
        rollupPluginCssOnly({
            output: 'public/build/extra.css'
        }),
```

**html page**
I use svelte but this can be converted to plain html easily (using for example getDocumentById to get the element).

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
  import './extra.css'
  import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'
  var containerElt: HtmlDivElement
  onMount(() => {
    monaco.editor.create(containerElt, {
      value: ['function x() {', '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");', '}'].join(
        '\n',
      ),
      language: 'javascript',
    })
  })
</script>

<style>
  div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<svelte:head />
<div bind:this={containerElt} />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, because you seem to be using Webpack, which I mentioned I didn't want to use. Are you using a different bundler?

Comment: I just wanted to show you what worked for me.
I am using rollup.

Comment: Makes live-reloading terribly slow, but works!